# Ошибка 404 в ответе cURL

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос. Я отправляю post данные с помощью cURL на другой сайт. Мне нужно проверить если в курле введен не существующий url сайта, то в итоге возвращается стр. 404. Как сделать проверку что возвращена именно страница 404? Поиском подстроки 404 в принятом html или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень индивидуально для каждого сайта.

"Правильная" 404 страница отдаёт http_code  404, но к сожалению не все сайты правильные. Многие отдают 200 ОК на 404 ошибку.

Кроме того, каждый сайт может сделать свою кастомную 404 страничку с уникальным дизайном. Там может вообще не встретиться 404 (легко: сделано картиной)

Поэтому нужно смотреть на конкретный сайт и анализировать конкретно его особенности. Кроме того, принятый алгоритм может вдруг перестать работать после редизайна сайта.

Искать в теле только 404 чревато изредка ложными срабатываниями -- особенно если на сайте много разных цифр и таблиц -- может найтись и такая, на которой 404 встречается.

Увы, серебряной пули нет. Подбирайте под конкретный сайт свой собственный алгоритм.

PS Классический ответ 404 в http_code реализуется так:

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* Handle 404 here. */
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Пример отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php
Также см. в документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: Согласен, либо на заголовке завязываться, либо на содержимом 404 страницы (в случае если отдает 200 ОК).

Comment: @A K Я проверил. Страница выдает заголовок Status Code:404 Not Found. Как этот заголовок получить в php и обработать его?

Comment: @aleks_sk Копайте в сторону `curl_getinfo`: добавил пример и ссылку в ответ.

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо!